# The variables inside of the listener do not change

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, listener, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to design a little Java software which involves JDBC and Swing. What my current problem is, I changed the model and table in one of the button listeners, but those two variables still remain the same in the other listener which is for the table. Both model and table are static, and can be accessed from any place in the class. I looked up the debugger, and it showed that variables are changed outside of the listener, but inside the listener, the variables are still not changed. Why would this happen? How to solve it?

Probably this description is not clear enough, here's a more detailed process how the problem was generated:

Here's where the table and model are stored, they are global and static:

```
public class MainView extends JFrame {

    private static UserService userService = new UserService();
    private static ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
    private static JTable table;
    private static JScrollPane tableScrollPane;
    private static NewTableModel model = new NewTableModel(null);
    private static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    public MainView() {

    }
    public void addFrm() {
      //here's where the main view window and listeners were put, this function will be called when the window needs to be displayed
    }
}
```

Here is a table listener that finds which row is selected, and it can extract the text of the selected row. Every row corresponds to one class that stores a paragraph of text.

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            if ((table.getSelectedRow() > table.getRowCount()) || (table.getSelectedRow() < 0)) {
                textArea.setText("");
            }//every time after the table changed, the model will be changed, sometimes the row that user selected before the table might become unavailable which could cause invalid index
            else {
                textArea.setText(model.getNote(table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow())));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the button listener that I mentioned before, when this button is clicked, a new window will be displayed and user can manipulate the MySQL database in that new window. This part should have no problem as the data can be written into the MySQL database correctly. After this window closed, a window listener is inside of it which will invoke the `update()` function when the new window is closing.

```
jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//Add some items
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        AddView addView = new AddView("adder");
        addView.addFrm();//new Window was stored in the other class
        addView.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                update();
                super.windowClosing(e);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the `update()` function:

```
public static void update(){
    String item = Objects.requireNonNull(comboBox.getSelectedItem()).toString();
     //this is used to select different item from catagories
    List<ItemInfo> list = itemService.getSelectedItem(item);
     //this is used to get a item list from database
    model.setItemInfo(list);//model has been override, it has a item list that stores list
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    model.fireTableStructureChanged();
    table.setModel(model);//give a new model to the table
    table.validate();//update the table
    table.updateUI();
    tableScrollPane.validate();//table is put in a scrollpane, so update it as well
    tableScrollPane.updateUI();
    table.clearSelection();
}
```

Here's the problem, if I select a row from the table, then I click the button and open a new window to add something. After I close that new window, that thing is added correctly. The model is also updated via update function, but an exception would appear after I closed the new window. It shows an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 18 out of bounds for length 18
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at com.Other.NewTableModel.getValueAt(NewTableModel.java:35)
```

However, if I only clicked the button, but did not select any row in the table, the program will work properly: the table will also be refreshed after the new window is closed.

I checked the debugger, and found this is caused by the model that in the part of table listener, after I invoked `update()`, the model has been updated wherever it is, except the part in the listener. The model inside of this listener remains the same, and did not change. How could this happen? There is only one model which is totally the same variable and it is static and global.
Anyone can help me about it?

Some descriptions may not clear because I am not English speaker but I can explain if you ask more.

some addition
code NewTableModel:

```
import com.Model.ItemInfo;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.util.List;

public class NewTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<ItemInfo> itemInfo;
    private String[] column = new String[]{"Id","Name","Type","Number","Exp_Date","Adder","Exp.(day)","Added_Date"};

    public NewTableModel(List<ItemInfo> itemInfo){
        this.itemInfo = itemInfo;
    }

    public void setItemInfo(List<ItemInfo> itemInfo) {
        this.itemInfo = itemInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return itemInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return column.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
        Object data = "";
        switch (c){
            case 0:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_id().toString();
                break;
            case 1:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_name();
                break;
            case 2:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_type();
                break;
            case 3:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_number().toString();
                break;
            case 4:
                if(itemInfo.get(r).getItem_date() == null){
                    return "Not Available";
                }
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_date().toString();
                break;
            case 5:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_adder();
                break;
            case 6:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_expDay();
                break;
            case 7:
                data = itemInfo.get(r).getItem_add_date();
        }
        return data;

    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return this.column[column];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    public String getNote(int row){
        return itemInfo.get(row).getItem_notes();
    }

    public int getId(int row){
        return itemInfo.get(row).getItem_id();
    }
}
```

Full Stark tracer is here:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 19 out of bounds for length 19
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at com.Other.NewTableModel.getNote(NewTableModel.java:76)
    at com.View.MainView$2.valueChanged(MainView.java:163)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:219)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:186)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:723)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.setValueIsAdjusting(BasicTableUI.java:972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicTableUI.java:1185)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6651)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6416)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4858)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4858)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Please show the code of `NewTableModel`, and as far as I can tell, your stacktrace of the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is incomplete. Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Mark, I added

Comment: The problem is changed (don't know why) and it is like this right now: After I added item, if I click any of the row on the table, the same exception would happen, seems the model inside of the table listener does not change

Answer (score 0):

From the [full] stack trace, method `valueChanged` is calling method `getNote(int)` and passing invalid value for the parameter. (According to the stack trace, the passed value is 19 and the size of `itemInfo` is 19).

The code that calls `getNote`:

```java
textArea.setText(model.getNote(table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow())));
```

You need to debug your code and see what value `table.getSelectedRow()` is returning. Then you need to see what value `table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow())` is returning. Then you need to figure out why it is returning an invalid value.

If you want me to help you debug the code, then you need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello Abra, You are right, that's where I the problem is, for instance, the size of `itemInfo` was 19, then I added a new item and the `itemInfo` should be updated(as it is inside of  `model` and `model` is updated), but actually it didn't (it should update but not, that's what I am confusing to). And I have tried to create a  `minimal, reproducible example`, I cutted over half of the code, but it is still too large, how do I send them to you? should I upload them to Github so you can download them? because it contain's a lot of files that used to connect the database to make the example work.

Comment: Have you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Here is a quote: _Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem._ Write a single class that contains a only the _Swing_ components you need in order to reproduce the problem. Then edit your question and post that code. I'm not going to debug your whole project. I think that's asking a bit too much.

Comment: I see, I will try to add one later

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem, I think it's caused by some outdated libraries, I updated them and the bugs disappeared anyway. Thanks for helping me.